# Having trouble sorting without grouping/field collapsing in Solr

Tags: solr, solrnet

Is it possible to do a compound sort in solr without Field Collapsing?

If I have two car models, Ford and Chevy, can I sort first on Ford where price is less than 2,000, then Ford > 2,000, then the Chevy models? I would like to do this without grouping, and without applying a price sort to the Chevy models.

For example, something like `&sort=Model:"Ford" AND price:[0 TO 2000]`

so that I get:

```
Ford 1, $1000
Ford 2, $500
Ford 2, $1500
_________
Ford 3, $3000
Ford 3, $5000
_______
Chevy 1
Chevy 2
Chevy 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tinkered a bit with this, and I've come up with a solution based on the query() function, since you can use that together with sorting. I'm not sure about the performance, and depending on the number of documents in your index, that might not be important, so the only way is to try it and see if it performs. I've used `name` and `price` as my two fields in the schema, which I think would map to your `Model` and `price` fields.

The way sort works is that each clause is evaluated in order, so that the first sort description is performed first, then the next one if there's a draw, and so on.

I've removed url escaping and formatted everything a bit:

```
sort=query($sq1,0) asc,query($sq2,0) asc
     &sq1=name:Ford* AND price:[0 TO 1500]
     &sq2=name:Ford*
```

This implies that the first sort is performed on the query named in the `sq1=` URL parameter, but if there's a draw (which there will be, if there isn't a match), the query named under `sq2=` will be performed (`$sq1` and `$sq2` refers to these to queries, and a simple substitution will be made by Solr before evaluating the `query()` function).

I haven't provided a default sort order, but you could add `name asc` as a default sort. The `0` as the second argument to `query()` is a value that the sort will use if there isn't a match from the query (otherwise it'll use the score from the query). You could feed this value into `product()` and multiply with the price, to sort each of the "buckets" by `price` as well if needed.